# jsbin require is not defined

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, js-bin

Here is [the simplest example](https://jsbin.com/wataci/edit) of the web map using ArcGIS Javascript API in jsbin. 
I'm getting a Reference error: "require is not defined".

Does anyone know why is this happening since require should have been exposed by the Dojo loader which is included in ArcGIS JavaScript API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL to jsbin uses http**s** while the src attribute in your script tag uses http. Chrome is blocking the http requests. Either use https in your script tag or use [jsbin over http](http://jsbin.com/wataci/edit?html,js,output). The the map works (but you need to update the URL to [esri.css](http://js.arcgis.com/3.10/js/esri/css/esri.css), [more about esri.css](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/css.html)).